# ListView Memory Leak Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, listview, memory-leaks, windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light

I've got a ListView bound to an ObservableCollection of objects(containing image URI's), When I add more items to the ListView I am seeing a massive spike in memory. I think I have narrowed its down to being a problem with the UserModel's imageUri. see below.

```
public class UserModel : ObservableObject
{
    ...
     private string _imageUri;
    ...


    ...
    public string ImageUri
    {
        get
        {
            return _imageUri;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(() => ImageUri, ref _imageUri, value);
        }
    } 
}
```

photo model

```
public class PhotoModel : ObservableObject
{
    ...
    private UserModel _user;
    private string _imageUri;
    ...

    ...
    public UserModel User
    {
        get
        {
            return _user;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(() => User, ref _user, value);
        }
    }

    public string ImageUri
    {
        get
        {
            return _imageUri;
        }
        set
        {
            Set(() => ImageUri, ref _imageUri, value);
        }
    } 

}
```

Xaml Binding of ListView

```
<ListView
      x:Name="MostPopularListView"
      ItemsSource="{Binding PhotosCollection}"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MostPopularDataTemplate}"
      Margin="0,0,0,0"
      IsItemClickEnabled="True"/>
```

Listview template

```
       ...
       <Image 
          Source="{Binding ImageUri}"             
          Stretch="Fill" 
          Height="300" />

       ...

       <Ellipse 
            Width="40"
            Height="40" 
            Margin="10,0,0,10">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                 <ImageBrush>
                     <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                         <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding User.ImageUri}" />
                            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                      </ImageBrush>
                 </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            ...
```

As you can see my ListView data template has two images, one for the actual photo and one for the user. Both are these are showing correctly but when I continue to add more items to the list I am seeing a massive spike in memory.

See image:
[image: High Memory Profile]

However if I don't set UserModel.imageUri (UserModel.imageUri is null then for all PhotoModels) I dont see this spike in memory. 
[image: Low Memory Profile]

Both profiles are carrying out the same actions loading the same images (total 15). First photo is with user photos and second screenshot is without.

I think the problem is something to do with PhotoModel having a UserModel and doing Set(...). As you can see from the photos below property change event handler has a count of 140.

[image: Profile1]
[image]

Most of these are PhotoModels but i only ever have 15 PhotoModels max in the Collection. I do clear and re-add using two extension methods (could thee be causing it).

```
     public static void Repopulate<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        collection.Clear();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public static void AddObjects<T>(this ICollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            collection.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

I'd really appreciate some advice on how to handle the performance better and if this is a memory leak.

Comment: Having the same problem. I seem to have narrowed it down to the `ImageBrush` in the `Ellipse.Fill`. When I just replace the ellipse with normal image much less memory is used. See if that is the case for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with how `ImageBrush` decodes the larger image. You need to set the `DecodePixelHeight` and `DecodePixelWidth` of the `BitmapImage`

Credit: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2015/05/06/making-circular-images-in-xaml-easily.aspx